# Анимация появления через расширение

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, css-animation

Хочу переделать менюшку, что бы она появлялась через расширение контента.

То есть при нажатии на кнопку менюшка начинает расширяться и в результате открывается полностью.

Ну и при повторном нажатии, сворачивалась.

Расширение и сужение по вертикали. То есть через изменение высоты.

При этом, если во время пока панель раскрывается кликнуть ещё раз, что бы она с этого места и начала обратно скрываться. И в другую сторону.

```js
function showHide() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  menu.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  align-items: center;
}

#myMenu a {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showHide()">спрятать / показать</button>

<div id="myMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">ссылка 1</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 2</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 3</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 4</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 5</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 6</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>что-то там ещё</p>
<p>что-то там ещё</p>
<p>что-то там ещё</p>
```

Comment: Вы хотите реализовать все на css? и второе уточнение, коли-во элементов меню известно?

Comment: Решение подходит любое. Количество элементов не известно заранее.

Comment: @slowBro Поправка, без использование библиотек и фреймворков.

Answer (score 4):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то что-то в этом роде(при анимации `max-height` лучше указывать какую-нибудь реальную цифру, если вы напишите `max-height` развернутому элементу слишком большой, то в момент разворота будет наблюдаться рывок)

```js
function showHide() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  menu.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  align-items: center;
}

#myMenu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
}

#myMenu a {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#myMenu.hide {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(); return false;">спрятать / показать</a>

<div id="myMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">ссылка 1</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 2</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 3</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 4</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 5</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 6</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>что-то там ещё</p>
<p>что-то там ещё</p>
<p>что-то там ещё</p>
```

Comment: Да, всё хорошо, но высоту надо рассчитать в скрипте, я часто добавляю элементы меню, и нет возможности указать адекватный `max-height` заранее, более того менюшка заполняется динамически, часть пунктов.

Comment: для анимации можно указать и 2000px как max-height,  я думаю вы же знаете у вас 5 элементов или 50.Просто в таком случае, плавность анимации вкл/выкл будет оличатся

Comment: я попробовал при больших `max-height`, перед закрытием пауза, понятно почему. Так мне не годится, хочется сделать что-бы идеально работало, без артефактов.

Comment: + мой ловите, но приму только полностью подходящее для меня решение

Comment: еще как вариант, можно анимировать высоту каждого элемента меню (если их высота фиксирована). но тогда получается небольшой эффект "гармошки"

Comment: я на основе вашего решения уже нашёл решение, завтра буду проверять, буду динамически рассчитывать максимальную высоту, и добавлять стилем в таблицу стилей, через https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Comment: сделал решение, можете посмотреть мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("myMenu").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("myMenu").classList.toggle("showMenu");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #606060;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  background: orange;
}

#myMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  transition: top .5s, height .5s;
}

#myMenu.showMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: top .5s, height .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="myMenu">myMenu</div>
</div>
```

Вариант со списком пунктов

```js
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("myMenu").classList.toggle("showMenu");
  document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].classList.toggle("spanActive");

  for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    menu[i].classList.toggle("menuActive");
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #606060;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  background: orange;
}

#myMenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  transition: top .5s, height .5s;
}

#myMenu.showMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: top .5s, height .5s;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.2;
  transition: background .5s, color .5s;
}

span.spanActive {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.2;
  transition: background .5s, color .5s;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.2;
  margin-top: 3px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.menu.menuActive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.2;
  margin-top: 3px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="myMenu">
    <span>myMenu</span>
    <p class="menu">menu - 1</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 2</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 3</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 4</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 5</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 6</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 7</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 8</p>
    <p class="menu">menu - 9</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня height заранее не известен, и он может быть больше высоты экрана, я в вопросе добавил заготовку

Comment: Дмитрий, щас сделаю и третий вариант

Comment: можно к именно моей заготовке

Comment: @Air Всё круче и круче

Answer (score 2):

Решил задачу, на основе решения @slowBro .

Основная идея эта `transition max-height`, для корректной работы сначала вычисляется реальный вертикальный размер блока, так как для `transition` нужно знать начальные и конечные значения.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("myMenu");

function showHide() {
  menu.classList.toggle("show");
}

function prepairMenuToShowHide() {

  /* показываем меню что бы вычислить его размер */
  menu.style.display = "block";
  menu.style.maxHeight = "5000px";
  var height = menu.clientHeight;

  /* теперь прячем обратно */
  menu.style.maxHeight = "";
  menu.style.overflow = "hidden";

  /* добавляем стиль с максимальной высотой, но не к элементу напрямую а в таблицу стилей */
  var rule = document.createElement("style");
  rule.innerHTML = `#myMenu.show { max-height: ${height}px;}`;
  document.head.appendChild(rule);

  /* добавляем класс транзиции к меню, если его сразу добавить работа будет не как ожидается*/
  /* setTimeout это хак, без него работать будет некорректно */
  setTimeout(`menu.classList.add("menuTransition")`, 0);
}

prepairMenuToShowHide();
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  align-items: center;
}

#myMenu {
  display: none;
  max-height: 0;
}

.menuTransition {
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}

#myMenu a {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showHide()">спрятать / показать</button>

<div id="myMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">ссылка 1</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 2</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 3</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 4</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 5</a>
    <a href="#">ссылка 6</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>что-то там ещё</p>
<p>что-то там ещё</p>
<p>что-то там ещё</p>
```